How many user interactions are needed to build an affinity for use in Einstein Recipes?
I'm trying to understand general feasibility of some use cases leveraging Einstein Recipes in Marketing Cloud Personalization. Specifically, how many interactions with our website does a visitor have to take before MCP can start building an affinity? The majority of our web traffic is new, anonymous visitors. Does anyone know what is a good ballpark number of interactions (sessions, pageviews, clicks, etc.) to establish a healthy affinity score?
